# Undo text change on blur if user does not confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user leaves a text box, I want to popup a confirmation asking if they are sure they want to make a change. If they answer no, then I would like the text box to undo their changes.

Is there a very simple way to do this, or do I have to manually keep track of what the initial value was myself?

(I know how to do the confirmation, just asking about the undo part)

Comment: You will have to store the original value somewhere. But, this is a simple thing to do.

Comment: *«do I have to manually keep track of what the initial value was »* == Sure! There is no magic in this world.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That's a silly thing to say. There are all kinds of things like this that are handled for us by the tools we use. Just because the dom doesn't hold onto the initial value doesn't mean it couldn't have been designed to do so. My hope was that it did and that there was a way to easily retrieve it. So not sure why you would associate that with "magic".

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette is defaultValue not what I was looking for? Is this the magic you were saying didn't exist, or am I missing something obvious here? (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp)

Comment: Sorry if my comment insulted you. I don't think it was mischievous... Possibly sacastic though. Note that I could have simply downvoted and posted [that link](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) in comment. Have a good day!

Comment: No worries... I wasn't insulted or offended. I was just giving you a hard time because I thought it was silly to reference magic in this case. You are still welcome to down vote if you like; that won't hurt my feelings either. Hope you also have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defaultValue is what I was looking for:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp

Answer (score 3):

You do have to store the old value, but it's pretty simple to do with a variable that gets set upon each confirmed change:

```js
let lastConfirmedValue = "";  // Last good value is stored here

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function(evt){
  if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
    lastConfirmedValue = this.value;  // Update the last committed value
  } else {
    evt.preventDefault();             // Cancel the event
    this.value = lastConfirmedValue;  // Put old value back
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Since you've asked about `defaultValue`, let me show you how it works:

```js
let txt1 = document.getElementById("one");
let txt2 = document.getElementById("two");


console.log("Box 1 defaultValue: " + one.defaultValue,
            "Box 2 defaultValue: " +  two.defaultValue);
            
// Now change the values of both
txt1.value = "something";
txt2.value = "somthing else";

console.log("Box 1 defaultValue: " + one.defaultValue,
            "Box 2 defaultValue: " +  two.defaultValue);
            
// Now change the values of both again
txt1.value = "abc";
txt2.value = "xyz";

console.log("Box 1 defaultValue: " + one.defaultValue,
            "Box 2 defaultValue: " +  two.defaultValue);
```

```html
<input id="one">
<input id="two" value="CT">
```

Comment: Ah... thanks, this is not as bad as I thought. I was thinking at first that the change event would fire on every keypress. Glad I was mistaken about that :)

Comment: @BVernon Nope, the `input`, `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events can be triggered on individual key strokes, but the `change` event only fires when the field loses the focus and the new value is different from the old one. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.

Comment: I am very confused now though... defaultValue looks to be *exactly* what I was looking for but you guys are acting as if you did not know about this. Did you really not know about it or am I missing something here? (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp)

Comment: `defaultValue` is used to reset an element back to it's **first** original value. You want a value that can change. Also, stay as far away as you can from W3 Schools. It's well-known to have incomplete, out of date, or flat out wrong information.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case that's fine because I am submitting the form immediately if they select yes. But even if I wasn't I could update defaultValue to be the new value (assuming I never needed to know the original defaultValue). I get that this might not have been your first recommendation, but just seems like a pretty big omission not to even mention it even if with some disclaimers.

Comment: Thanks for your help though... not meaning to sound ungrateful :)

Comment: You're mistaken.

Comment: Dude... do you always just assume you are right when someone tells you that you are mistaken? The link I just share LITERALLY gives an example of changing it. And I have already tried it in my own code.

Comment: I was mistaken about it's ability to be set. My bad. Having said that, your solution is exactly the same as what I've shown except instead of my `lastConfirmedValue` variable, you're using `defaultValue`. However, the rest of the logic and functionality would be what I've shown.

Comment: Yes, it would be the same if I needed to track changes. But in my case if user confirms a change then I immediately submit the form, so if they don't confirm I just set the value back to the defaultValue. Easy peasy. :)

Comment: @BVernon Or, you just set the value back to `lastConfirmedValue`. Also easy peasy ;)

Comment: Lol. Yes Scott, I could create an additional variable to store the data that is already available in defaultValue. I don't see the point of it, but it would certainly work and it would also be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the appropriate events and then take action when those events occur:

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('#inputEl');
let temp;

//Update the temp value each time we focus on the input
inputEl.addEventListener('focus', e => {
  temp = e.target.value;
});

//Confirm that the user wants to keep their changes
inputEl.addEventListener('change', e => {
  var confirmed = confirm('Are you sure you want to save these changes?');
  if (!confirmed) {
    e.target.value = temp;
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="inputEl">Enter a value</label>
<input id="inputEl" type="text">
```